# how to do loops in bottlepy templates?

Tags: python, template-specialization

I know it's a simple question, but I have strange behaviour in here.

```
<pre>
          %for key in tags_photo:
          %   try:
                {{ key }} :  {{ exif[tags_photo[key]].raw_value }}
          %   except KeyError:
          %        continue
          %end
</pre>
```

I assume that only content in pre tag should be repeated like in jinja2..?
But now I got a loop of the whole template..(i mean pre tags repeated also) why??

how to do properly loops in bottlepy template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close all of your blocks:

```
<pre>
%for key in tags_photo:
    %try:
        {{ key }} :  {{ exif[tags_photo[key]].raw_value }}
    %except KeyError:
        %continue
    %end
%end
</pre>
```

(In the code you posted in the OP, the one `%end` was only closing the `try`/`except` block, so the `for` block was extending to the end of the template.)

Comment: I thought closing block is only for closing python code block.. thank you so much =)